# Promise { <pending> } in Deno(typescript)

Tags: typescript, promise, deno

I wrote a simple API application Deno in `typescript`. I used promises to send the response. but I got Promis pending error. What went wrong here?

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

> server.ts

```
import { Application,Router,Context } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import {login,auth,guest} from './router.ts';

const router=new Router();

router
    .post('/login',login);

    const app=new Application();
    app.use(router.routes());
    app.use(router.allowedMethods());

    app.listen({port:8000});
    console.log('started port 8000');
```

> Router.ts

```
import {Context } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

export const login= async (ctx:Context)=>
{
   const {value}= await ctx.request.body();
   ctx.response.body=value;
   console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: I checked this typescript module on deno.land.
Are you sure that the body is a function?

Comment: yes. login function wants to return the request body. I just learning deno

Comment: Right but what type of it? Could you make ```console.log(ctx.request.body)``` and ```console.log(typeof ctx.request.body)``` ?

Comment: You are calling login from .post but in login you were expecting to pass ctx which will be null in your case.  What does your console.log shows?

Comment: empty '{}' in the postman, after i deleted the peomises also i'm getting the same error again

Comment: @RafatSarosh please I visited your profile can you able to answer this question. because you are working on azure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004153/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-microsoft-teams-app-in-our-custom-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://deno.land/x/oak@v6.5.0)  `body().value` is a `Promise<unknown>` (assuming that you are sending JSON), so you need to move your `await` to the value:

```
export const login= async (ctx:Context)=>
{
   const value = await ctx.request.body().value;
   ctx.response.body= value;
   console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. a lot of love from me